# How to find factorial without using Recursion or loop in java?

Tags: java, factorial

I need to find the factorial in java without using loop or recursion ?
So if there is any way then please help . Thanks

Comment: You can't really compute a factorial without loop nor recursion.

Comment: you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation.

Comment: You can always [parse this page](http://membres.multimania.fr/rsirdey/facttabl.htm) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly impractical but no explicit loop anywhere.

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class Fac {
    public static int fac(final int _n) {
        final ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);
        final Timer timer = new Timer(0, null);
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int result = 1;
            int n = _n;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                result *= n;
                n--;
                if(n == 0) {
                    try {
                        queue.put(result);
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                    }
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = queue.take();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fac(10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Stirling approximation for Gamma function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

[image]

But it will be not precise.

Answer (score 2):

There is another post on here which you might like to have a look at:

[Is there a method that calculates a factorial in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891031/is-there-a-method-that-calculates-a-factorial-in-java)

Also - this link has lots of different implementations for factorial functions - you might find what you are looking for on here.  At the very least, you will learn tons about factorials..

http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner solution, though internally it is doing a loop, as it can't possible without it, but you don't need to do it yourselves:

```
Long factorialNumber = LongStream.rangeClosed(2, N).reduce(1, Math::multiplyExact);
```

Answer (score 0):

You precompute the values.

More seriously, it's not really doable, since recursion and loops are inevitable if you might need to do arbitrarily much computation.

Answer (score -1):

We can do a functional factorial in Java 8 :

```
package com.promindis.jdk8;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import static java.math.BigInteger.*;

public class Factorial implements TCO {

  private TailCall<BigInteger> factorialTCO(
    final BigInteger fact, final BigInteger remaining) {
    if (remaining.equals(ONE))
      return done(fact);
    else
      return call(() ->
        factorialTCO(fact.multiply(remaining), dec(remaining)));
  }

  private BigInteger dec(final BigInteger remaining) {
    return remaining.subtract(ONE);
  }

  private BigInteger apply(final String from) {
    return factorialTCO(ONE, new BigInteger(from)).invoke();
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Factorial().apply("5"));
    System.out.println(new Factorial().apply("100"));

  }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/globulon/lambda-jdk8/blob/master/src/com/promindis/jdk8/Factorial.java)

Comment: although TBH both this and SpiderPig's solutions are just playing with semantics...it's recursion, but not your regular 'function call' type recursion.