# How to get the factorial value

Tags: java, apache-commons, factorial

I want to get the factorial value of a number. I read in a wiki that I can expect the result of 5! to be 5x4x3x2x1 = 120. Now how can I get that in Java?

```
BigFraction g = new BigFraction(5);
System.out.println(g.getNumerator());
```

This prints just 5.

In the end i want to calculate combinations in a network:

[image: network]

Which has the following formula:

[image: example from wiki]

Comment: You mean `factorial` value?

Comment: You seem to be confusing *[fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics))* and *[factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)*.

Comment: I assume you can start wit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891031/is-there-a-method-that-calculates-a-factorial-in-java

Comment: or http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=622

Comment: A naive student implementation of factorial is rarely a good idea.  You ought to be looking at lngamma and binomial functions.

Comment: yeah i mean factorial, i remembered incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, why not just use the plain old formula:

```
x=n*(n-1)/2
```

Where n is the number of vertices.

For this simple task, you don't have to use a computationally intensive function as a factorial...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing *[fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29)* and *[factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)*.

If you want the *factorial*, you can use [ArithmeticUtils.factorial](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html#factorial%28int%29) for that:

```
long factorial = ArithmeticUtils.factorial(5);
System.out.println(factorial); // "120"
```

Comment: How can i deal with large numbers?
`long factorial = ArithmeticUtils.factorial(89);` gives a MathArithmeticException

Comment: @clankill3r: That's a *different* question.

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava's [`BigIntegerMath`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html).

To calculate the factorial i.e. `n!`:

```
BigInteger factorial = BigIntegerMath.factorial(n);
```

To calculate the binomial i.e. `n! / (k! (n - k)!)`:

```
BigInteger binomial = BigIntegerMath.binomial(n, k);
```

(Similar functionality for `int` and `long` is available in [`IntMath`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html) and [`LongMath`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html) respectively.)