# Is it possible to write a loop in Java that does not actually use a loop method?

Tags: java, loops

I was curious if, in Java, you could create a piece of code that keeps iterating a piece of code without the use of a `for` or `while` loop, and if so, what methods could be used to solve this?

Comment: The magic word is **recursion**.

Comment: What would recursion do, like how would it be used?

Comment: Yeah, recursion.  It will blow your mind, if not your stack.

Comment: By `Stack`, are you referring to the stacking of factorials that was mentioned in ComputerPhile's video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ha78yWRDlE

Comment: We're referring to the stack that keeps track of methods called but not yet returned from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). A recursive function is a function which calls itself until a base case is reached. An example is the factorial function:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int result;

    if(n==1)
        return 1;

    result = fact(n-1) * n;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! I will mark it as correct as soon as the 9 minutes are up.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Java 8 [Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) methods for iterating over the elements of a Collection. Among the methods you can use are filtering methods (get all the elements of a collection that satisfy some conditions), mapping methods (map a Collection of one type to a Collection of another type) and aggregation methods (like computing the sum of all the elements in a Collection, based on some integer member of the Element stored in the collection).

For example - [Stream forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) :

```
List<Element> = new ArrayList<Element>();
...
list.stream().forEach (element -> System.out.println(element));
```

Or you can do it [without a Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) :

```
List<Element> = new ArrayList<Element>();
...
list.forEach (element -> System.out.println(element));
```

Comment: Any references or examples?

Comment: I'm not going to mark this as correct, as I would like to see some more solutions, but if I do not receive anymore it will be given to you.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of recursion:

```
public class LoopException extends Exception {
    public LoopException(int i, int max) throws LoopException {
        System.out.println( "Loop variable: "+i);
        if (i < max)
          throw new LoopException( i+1, max );
    }
}
```

Of course this is just a bit of fun, don't ever do it for real.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a `goto` statement ([that's a lie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)), so that way is a dead end.

But you could always make a piece of code endlessly iterate using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Old [factorial function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891031/is-there-a-method-that-calculates-a-factorial-in-java) seems to be the favorite, but since it is not an infinite loop, I will go for this simple function:

```
int blowMyStack(int a) {
    return blowMyStack(a + 1);
}
```

There will be many ways to do this using various features of the language. But it always falls to an underlying recursion.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're referring of something like C's goto, the answer is no.

In other cases, you can use recursive functions.