# Understanding why my for loop does not work to approximate e

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, eulers-number

e can be approximated using the formula e = 1 + (1/1!) + (1/2!) + (1/3!)... + (1/n!). I am trying to use for loops to accept whatever integer the user sets n to be. The program should approximate e by using the formula above from (1/1!) + .... (1/n!) and out put the result.

The nested for loop calculates the factorial of n (tested it separately and it works) and the variable defined, frac, puts the factorial into a fraction of 1/(answer to factorial). I store the value into a variable e and it should add the new fraction to the old value every time an iteration is done. I cannot not understand what is wrong with my loops that they are not out putting the right answer.

```
System.out.println("Enter an integer to show the result of 
approximating e using n number of terms.");
int n=scan.nextInt();
double e=1;
double result=1;
for(int i=1; n>=i; n=(n-1))
{
    for(int l=1; l<=n; l++)
            {
                result=result*l;
            }
    double frac=(1/result);
    e=e+frac;
}
System.out.println(e);
```

Output when I enter the integer 7 as n = 1.0001986906956286

Comment: This is not javascript

Comment: That is *not* how you calculate a factorial. When i = 3, "result" ends up as 1 * 1 * 2 * 1 * 2 * 3 =  12 because you don't reset to 1 after each iteration of i. Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891031/is-there-a-method-that-calculates-a-factorial-in-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that whole inner loop. All you need is `result *= i`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    result *= i;
    double frac = (1 / result);
    e += frac;
}
```

Here's a JavaScript version I just threw together:

```
function init() {
  const elem = document.getElementById('eapprox');

  let eapprox = 1;
  const n = 15;
  let frac = 1;

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    frac /= i;
    eapprox += frac;
  }

  elem.textContent = eapprox;
}
```

This yields 2.718281828458995. Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OgXbr36dKce21urHH1Ge?p=preview

Comment: Yes, Java (and JavaScript too, and C, and a bunch of languages) have shorthand operators +=, -=, *=, /= for adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing a variable and putting the result back into that variable.

Comment: After trying to understand exactly what your java code is doing I am a little confused. For the first answer you gave me I am using n as whatever input the user types, so if they input n to be 7 (the code should output e = 1 + (1/7!) + (1/6!) + ... (1/1!), how is the for loop stopping if you are counting up with n? Wouldn't i(1) always be less than or equal to n(7) since n is counting up by 1 each iteration? Im not understanding why this is not an endless loop. I really appreciate the help with this, have never coded in any language before this semester!

Comment: The reason it doesn't make sense is I made a typo :) You're right, it would keep going forever. I fixed the typo without even realizing when I did the JavaScript version.